# PDO equivalent of mysql_client_encoding()?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, pdo

Is there any way in PDO to check the client encoding, like there was in mysql/mysqli with `mysql_client_encoding();`?

On PHP.net it states that one can set the charset with `PDO::setAttribute()`, e.g.:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

But how does one *get* the current charset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different character sets at issue:

- the encoding in which MySQL assumes strings are sent by the client ([`character_set_client`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client)); and
- the encoding in which MySQL will send its responses ([`character_set_results`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_results)).

To ascertain the current value of these variables using PDO, you could fetch the results of the relevant [`SHOW VARIABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-variables.html) statement; for example:

```
$qry = $db->query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_client'");
```

The documentation for [`mysql_client_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php) is somewhat ambiguous, as it states:

> Retrieves the ***`character_set`*** variable from MySQL.

However, no such server system variable exists: so I'm not sure which it would return.

Finally, rather than setting a `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`, you can specify your desired character set in the DSN (as mentioned [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)):

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host;charset=$charset", $user, $password);
```

Comment: Hi, Not sure what it's return either. I know how to set the variable, but I have read many places that the charset='' is ignored, and that `$db->exec( "SET NAMES 'utf8'");` should be used instead.