# MySQL sometimes not returning the same results to php as to workbench

Tags: php, mysql, meekro

My project is a webapp that reads a database and sends emails.
I inserted the database today and with the "example" one was working okay but did not have so many rows as the real one.

**My problem is that something(database side) in one of the queries that I do is making the $results empty.**

```
$selected_category = (isset($_POST['category'])) ? $_POST['category'] : null;
$group = (isset($_POST['group'])) ? $_POST['group'] : null;

if ($selected_category) {

    if ($selected_category && $group) {
        //para se for selecionado o grupo

        if ($selected_category == "-1") {
            //para todas as categorias juntas
            if ($group == "-1") {
                $results = DB::query("SELECT category, name, email FROM clients LIMIT 100");
            } else {
                $results = DB::query("SELECT category, name, email FROM clients LIMIT %i, 100",$group );
            }

        } else {
            //para as categorias
            if ($group == "-1") {
                $results = DB::query("SELECT category, name, email FROM clients WHERE category = %i LIMIT 100", $selected_category );
            } else {
                $results = DB::query("SELECT category, name, email FROM clients WHERE category = %i LIMIT %i, 100", $selected_category, $group );
            }
        }

error_log(mysql_error());
        echo json_encode($results);
    } else {
        //para se for selecionada a categoria
        //se for -1 manda todas as categorias
        if ($selected_category == "-1") {
            //MAL
            $count = DB::query("SELECT COUNT(category) AS cat FROM clients");
            $count["category"] = "all";
            echo json_encode($count);
            //$results = DB::query("SELECT category, name, email FROM clients");
        } else {
            $count = DB::query("SELECT COUNT(category) AS cat FROM clients WHERE category = %i", $selected_category );
            //$results = DB::query("SELECT category, name, email FROM clients WHERE category = %i", $selected_category );
            $cat = DB::query("SELECT name FROM categories WHERE super_id = %i", $selected_category);
            $count["category"] = $cat;
            echo json_encode($count);
        }


    }

    //echo json_encode($results);
}
```

This is the part where I think the error is.
Notice that **the variables I change are** the **$category** and to select the limit in the query (**$group**).

*A practicable example is when I make $selected_category = -1 (that means I want all the categories) and I make $group = -1 (the first 100 rows) or $group = 100 (the 100 rows after the 100º row), mysql returns the correct values. But when I make $group = 200 (to select the 100 rows after the row 200º), **mysql does not return anything and I get and empty array**.*

**Do any of you have any idea that could be corrupting my data?** 
I have trimmed it already and it did nothing. I'm really stuck and I need to finish this untill next friday or I don't get paid!

Thank you all! And hope someone can help me.

**EDIT:**
So, I have already did:
**1 -** changed the database to utf-8 following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8) answer; 
**2 -** changed the two lines that say `latin1` in the meekrodb file to `utf8`; 
**3 -** Added the ut8_encode php function to the $results

```
$json = utf8_encode(json_encode( $results )); 
        if ( $json === false ) echo "ERROR: " . json_last_error_msg(); else echo $json;
```

Now I no longer have the utf_8 json error, but $results still come empty.

**EDIT2**
I passed all of this to the production server and guess what.... it works.
Somethings I can't understand yet. Thank you all that spent time with my problem! :)

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients` say?

Comment: What database extension are you using in the `DB` class

Comment: It says 510. Maybe something in the data is corrupted in some rows but I can't know what..

Comment: What do you think `%i` is supposed to be doing? Do you mean `$i`?? Although I dont see where `$i` is being set to anything

Comment: Hm. Could you print the query just before you execute it, just to be sure it is exactly `SELECT category, name, email FROM clients LIMIT 200, 100`?

Comment: I am using meekrodb so I guess it is the way to save that space for the variable that comes after. I don't know where I set the database extension but it works in most of the cases.. Just in a few it doesn't..  Thanks for giving some thought on it guys

Comment: I dont recognise a `DB::query()` function that takes one or two extra parameters, so you had better show us the DB Class as well, or at least the `query()` method

Comment: @RiggsFolly [see here](http://meekro.com/docs.php#anchor_query)

Comment: @Kenny Ah thanks. Not come across that one before. So it looks like MYSQLI made to look like PDO. Wow thats a productive concept

Comment: I don't reaaly know how to print the query, but it has to be ok cause you remembered me to var_dump($results) and I console.log(response) from AJAX request and I got the results I want.
But if I json_encode($results), they disappear..

Comment: Ah, there might be an encoding error. Test the result value of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for `false`, and use [json_last_error_msg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) if it is.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do it? Thank you very much!

Comment: `$json = json_encode( $results ); if ( $json === false ) echo "ERROR: " . json_last_error_msg(); else echo $results`. (I added links to the documentation, you should check them out).

Comment: ERROR: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded. I'm starting to use ajax, I didn't know about this. Thanks for the help! Could you lead me on what to do with this error?

Comment: You're welcome, and sure; if you can't [set the client connection encoding for mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552528/pdo-equivalent-of-mysql-client-encoding) because of meekro, you can use [mb_convert_encoding](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) and [mb_detect_encoding](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) if you don't know the database encoding. You'll probably have to `array_map` the results to fix certain columns.

Comment: Or, [convert the db to utf8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8).

Comment: @Kenney I will try that as soon as possible and post the result. Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: I have converted db to utf-8 through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8) answer. Still the same error... Any suggestion?